# Search a column with id in Sqlite database

Tags: android

I want to search a column by using an id.
That function will return all the values in that particular row.

Here's my code and log.

**LOG**:

```
09-19 14:00:54.940      618-618/? **I/SqliteDatabaseCpp﹕ sqlite returned: error code = 1, msg = table IUBConnectivitydata already exists, db=/data/data/com.example.sivs.datacopy/databases/**
09-19 14:00:54.970      618-618/? E/SQLiteOpenHelper﹕ Couldn't open Database1 for writing (will try read-only):
```

**Code:**

```
 public Cursor Rowdata(String a){
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
        Log.d("a4","aaa34");
        Cursor cursor1=db.rawQuery("SELECT "+COL_3+", FROM" + TABLE_NAME + "where WBTSID==?",new String[] {a});
        Log.d("a3","row");
        return cursor1;
    }
```

Comment: Before looking any deeper, you've forgotten to place spaces between `FROM`, `TABLE_NAME` and `where`. In addition, I think you'll find there's is only one `=` in a `WHERE` clause.

Comment: The most inteteresting part of the log is would be the stacktrace below "Couldn't open Database1 for writing (will try read-only):"

Comment: thanks e4c5 and PPartisan i found why it cant open. but now it is showing  sqlite syntax error.       Cursor cursor1=db.rawQuery("SELECT "+COL_3+", FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " where WBTSID==?",new String[] {a});

Answer (score 1):

You added an extra comma before FROM, an extra = before ? and forgot 2 spaces around the table name.

Wrong:

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT "+COL_3+", FROM" + TABLE_NAME + "where WBTSID==?",new String[] {a});
```

Right:

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT "+COL_3+" FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " where WBTSID=?",new String[] {a});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend only one global database helper class instance, which can be located in the extended application class. The helper class itself must hold an instance of `SQLiteDatabase`, which is the actual database object.

It can look like this:

```
public MyClass extends Application {
    private MyDBHelper db;
    public MyDBHelper getDB() {
        if (database == null) {
            db = new MyDBHelper(this);
        }
        db.open(); // call getWritableDataBase internally
        return db;
    }
}
```

If you create the database in the SqlLiteHelpers `onCreate()` callback, then it should be only created the very first time you open the app after installation.

In the `onOpen()` callback of SqlLitehelper you can activate foreign key constraints with `setForeignKeyConstrainsEnabled(true)`, which is an important safety feature. Of coure you have to declare foreign keys with `REFERS()` clauses.

EDIT: Creating a synchronized static instance is also possible (as stated in the comment below). Anyway you must ensure that there exists only one instance of your database helper class and only one instance of the database itself. (Which must be located in the database helper class)

Comment: Another method (and I would say more popular) is to create a `static synchronized` `singleton` inside the `MyDBHelper` class: http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/05/correctly-managing-your-sqlite-database.html

Answer (score 0):

try following,

```
if (c.moveToFirst()){ 
   do{ 
       id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));
   }while(cursor.moveToNext());
}
```

c is a cursor of all data.